# Register SPO Hub Site CSOM

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I know that it's possible to register a site as a hub Site using the PowerShell cmdlet `Register-SPOHubSite` but I haven't been able to find an option to do this via CSOM.

Has anyone been able to do this using C#?

**update**

I've found the `HubSiteCreationInformation` object in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` namesapce but there is very limited information in the [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.hubsitecreationinformation.aspx) for the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `RegisterHubSite` method to register it as Hub Site.

You need to use the code as below:

```
var tenantSiteUrl  = "https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com/"

// your method to get clientContext

var context = GetClientContext(adminSiteUrl);

var tenant = new Tenant(context);

tenant.RegisterHubSite("https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/testSiteCollection");

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Reference - [Tenant.RegisterHubSite method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.registerhubsite.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Gautam, I should have guessed it was from the tenant! This has helped me with my next query. Setting the hub logo, which you can do with `LogoUrl` property of the `HubSiteProperties` object. Returned by the `RegisterHubSite` method